# Что за ограничения в названии класса?

Tags: java

Почему с именем класса `ArrayApp` всё хорошо, а если назвать класс `LowArrayApp`, то получается ошибка?

```
class LowArray
{

}

class ArrayApp // LowArrayApp - почему не дает так назвать?
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

    }
}
```

Только не надо говорить, что второй класс надо кинуть в другой файл ;)

Comment: если второй класс public - то нужно бросать в другой файл. Если private - нет.

Comment: KoVadim, если дописать private к классу ArrayApp в Eclipse будет ошибка

Comment: ну если приписать error, то тоже лучше не будет:) нужно знать где и как можно "дописать".

Comment: Как называется ваш файл? В одном ли файле оба класса?

Comment: название файла: LowArray.java

Comment: в этом файле оба класса

Comment: KoVadim, код в студию ;)

Comment: ну тогда это должно выглядеть либо так:  
<pre><code>
class LowArray{
 public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    }
class ArrayApp {
    
}// end class ArrayApp
}// end class LowArray
<pre><code>   
либо писать в разные файлы, иначе работать не будет...
то есть нужно один класс сделать внутренним, если хотите поместить оба класса в один файл

Comment: мне очень “нужно знать где и как можно "дописать"  “   ;)

Comment: спасибо, вариант интересный, но меня интересует, почему компилятор ищет в моем исходном примере именно класс ArrayApp?

Comment: а почему я должен показывать код? Показывайте код, а мы уже поищем, где и что поправить.

Comment: что за неприязнь к названию класса LowArrayApp?  ;)

Comment: Потому что такое имя у файла. ArrayApp.java

Comment: ну из вашего кода(с первого поста) видно, что в ArrayApp находится метод main, поэтому компилятор ищет именно его, попробуйте назвать файл  ArrayApp.java,
по идее должно работать.  
То есть если меняете название класса с методом main, нужно также менять название файла.

Comment: KoVadim, имя файла: LowArray.java а не ArrayApp.java

Answer (score 1):

Я скомпилировал программой javac ваш код...

Вариант №1:

Код выполняется без проблем :

```
class LowArray
{

}

class LowArrayApp // выполняется без проблем
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

    }
}
```

В результате получается два файла **LowArray.class** и **LowArrayApp.class**

---

Вариант № 2:

Код выполняется без проблем :

```
class LowArray
{

}

class ArrayApp // выполняется без проблем
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

    }
}
```

В результате получается два файла **LowArray.class** и **ArrayApp.class**

...

Кстати... все кто писал про неправильное имя  файла с исходником, о том что его имя должно совпадать с именем класса, у которого объявлен метод **main**.

Ребята, вы ошибаетесь! Это условие действует только когда класс имеет модификатор доступа **public**. Здесь же в коде модификаторы доступа не указаны и имя файла может быть любым...
и после компиляции одного **.java** файла будет получено два **.class** файла.

Answer (score 0):

А Вы название файла с этим классом меняли? Файл с классом, содержащим метод main, должен иметь то же имя, что и этот класс.

Comment: да, менял!

Comment: Очень странно, только сейчас попробовал у себя дать классу такое имя - и без проблем все прошло. Что компилятор пишет?

Comment: Error: Could not find or load main class ArrayApp

Comment: это если я второй класс назвал LowArrayApp, а если я его называю ArrayApp ошибки нет

Comment: почему компилятор ищет  именно класс ArrayApp?

Comment: А что за компилятор у вас, простите? Если Eclipse, то отвечу наверняка, что в настройках запуска есть такое поле, в которое вы, собственно, вводите наименование главного класса, где компилятор будет искать функцию `main`, поле называется **Main class:**

Для иных компиляторов, думаю, что процедура та же, только я не подскажу где там эта настройка.

Answer (score 0):

исходя из того что вы предоставили на обозрение сложно предположить что вы пытаетесь сделать, поэтому позволю себе повторить общеизвестную информацию.

пример: 
вам нужно использовать какое-то сложное логгирование. вы реализовали общий функционал и инициализацию в классе BaseLogger, и в то же время предоставляете возможность использовать его базовую реализацию:

```
public abstract class BaseLogger
{
   public static BaseLogger getInstance ()
   {
      return new DefaultLogger ();
   }

   public abstract void log ( Object obj );

   /* Другие методы */
}

final class DefaultLogger extends BaseLogger
{
   @Override
   public void log ( final Object obj )
   {
      System.out.println ( obj );
   }
}
```

нет смысла классу DefaultLogger давать модификатор public, так как он не будет никем наследоватся и вообще где-то использоватся кроме класса BaseLogger. он нужен лишь для того чтоб потом не надо было вкручивать еще один отдельный класс для "дефолтного" логгера. так как он не public и используется в пределах класса BaseLogger, то нет смысла хранить его в отдельном файле.

в java public class всегда хранится в отдельном файле, имя которого совпадает с его именем (без имени пакета). package private классы (без модификатора public) можно хранить как в отдельных файлах (если они используются многими классами пакета) так и в одном файле в как в примере.